# Django admin custom admin widget, how to disable required?

Tags: python, django

ive added a custom widget to my admin form that just displays data and when i try save the form i get field is required on my custom widget, how can i set this to not required?

Thanks

forms.py

```
class TemplateVariablesWidget(forms.Widget):
    template_name = 'networks/config_variables.html'

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        c_vars = ConfigVariables.objects.all()
        context = {
            'ConfigVariables' : c_vars
        }
        return mark_safe(render_to_string(self.template_name, context))


class VariableForm(forms.ModelForm):
    variables = forms.CharField(widget=TemplateVariablesWidget)

    class Meta:
        model = ConfigVariables
        fields = "__all__"
```

admin.py

```
class ConfigTemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = VariableForm
    list_display = ('device_name', 'date_modified')

admin.site.register(ConfigTemplates, ConfigTemplateAdmin)
```

error:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the Django docs at the [Form fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#required) section.

```
class VariableForm(forms.ModelForm):
    variables = forms.CharField(widget=TemplateVariablesWidget, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ConfigVariables
        fields = "__all__"
```

But, take care, check if this field is not required in models.